# Oracle stored procedure running a SQL query while passing parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql

How would I write a stored procedure in Oracle Database which will:

1. Execute a SQL query
2. Give result set in XML format?

The SQL query that stored procedure has to run is like:

```
SELECT * from TBL1 where ID = USER_SUPPLIED_ID;
```

User has to enter value for "USER_SUPPLIED_ID" while executing the stored procedure.

Comment: Please post some more informations; for example, what should the XML format be? and what is the table structure? and why do you need a procedure? and, above all, what have you tried so far? Please post your code explaining the issues with it. You also may want to have a look at [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need a procedure for that:

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getxml ('SELECT * from TBL1 where ID = 1')
from dual;
```

But if you do want to put that into a function, you could do it like this:

```
create or replace function get_data(p_id integer)
  return clob
is
begin
  return dbms_xmlgen.getxml ('SELECT * FROM tbl1 where id = '||p_id);
end;
/
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I run the function? Can we convert into stored procedure?

Comment: @Rio: you call it like any other function e.g. like `count()`, `lower()` or the even `dbms_xmlgen.getxml()`. A procedure would need an out parameter to return something - I find that quite cumbersome. What exactly are you trying to do with that?

Comment: I am looking for a stored procedure. BTW, how can I run get_data(p_id) function from SQLPlus?

Comment: See my first statement - that's how you call a function